# What are the longform field names for the select statements in Microsoft Academic Graph Search?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm trying to use the JSON search endpoint for the MS Academic Knowledge Graph and finding it difficult to work out what the legal "Select" fields are.

For example, I am interested in the author's affiliation

```html
POST /academic/v1.0/graph/search?mode=json

{
 "path":"/v0/",

 "v0" : { 
    "match": {
  
      "Name": "stephen hawking",
  
    },
    
      "type": "Author",
       "select": [ "DisplayAuthorName", "AffiliationName" ]
 }
}
```

There is no obvious way of working out these field names. [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/academic-knowledge/entityattributes) gives the shortform entity names like "DAuN" which do not seem to work in the graph api.

Where can I get a comprehensive list of legal knowledge graph "select" fields?

Comment: What errors are you getting when you try and run the affiliation entities listed in the doc?

Comment: So if I were to run the above query but with `"select": [ "DisplayAuthorName", "AfN" ]` as in Affiliation Name which is a valid field in the evaluate endpoint,  I get a resultset but AfN is never populated.